# Calling API from Saleforce is giving error code 500

Tags: rest, salesforce

I have a **REST API** to callout from Salesforce.

The authorization of the API is through access token.

I am able to get the access token through POST request in Salesforce. Also tested from **Postman** through that token and able to get a successful response.

I am using the below code to callout the API using the access token:

```
    String endpoint_x = '*****';//Putting my endpoint here
    Http httpObject;
    HttpResponse response;
    String accessToken;
    accessToken = MyUtilityClass.getAccessToken();
    jsonBody = json.serializePretty('', true);//Yes, My JSON is empty
         
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        
    request.setEndpoint(endpoint_x);
        
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accessToken);
        
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setBody(jsonBody);
        
        
    httpObject = new Http();
    response = httpObject.send(request);
    System.debug('Response=' + response);
```

Getting Response value as below:

```
System.HttpResponse[Status=Internal Server Error, StatusCode=500]
```

I have tried putting '{}' in the Jsonbody. Added 'Content-Type' in header but nothing worked.

Where should I lookout for this?

Comment: Debug your accessToken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Postman**, I was not putting anything in the body, and getting a successful response.

To get the same behaviour, I was using empty string in Apex, like this:

```
jsonBody = json.serializePretty('', true);
```

But the parser was not working correctly.

To solve this, I created a class without any field:

```
class ClassForEmptyBody{
}
```

And used object of that class in the serializer:

```
ClassForEmptyBody classForEmptyBodyObject = new ClassForEmptyBody();
jsonBody = json.serializePretty(classForEmptyBodyObject , true);
```

Comment: Http http           = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        request.setEndpoint(this.endpoint);
        System.debug(this.endpoint);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', this.getAuthorization() );
        request.setBody(this.body);    
        System.debug(this.body);    I have the same code, but nothing ...all the time is 500...any ideas?

        return http.send(request);

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing json body if nothing is in there. Just skip setbody code and try.